# HTML5 <input type='range'>

Tags: html

I am using html5 type='range' sliders and there are 3 of them. My requirement is such that the total selected values of the 3 sliders must not go more than 250.
For eg: 
slider1 =100
slider2 =100
slider3 =50

and sum of these sliders must not cross 250 (sum = 100+100+50)which is true in the above example.

Pasting the fiddle link below. Also please open the fiddle link in chrome browser.

```
function updateSlider(obj){

    id = obj.id;
    sum = sum123();

    if(sum>250){

        alert('Max reached');
        return false;
    }
    document.getElementById('span'+id).innerHTML = obj.value 
}
function sum123(){
    var i = parseInt(document.getElementById('slide').value);
    var j = parseInt(document.getElementById('slide1').value);
    var k = parseInt(document.getElementById('slide2').value);
    var sum = i+j+k;
    if(sum>250){
        arr['i'] = i;
        arr['j'] = j;
        arr['k'] = k;
    }
    return i+j+k;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kapilgopinath/2yLuj/4/

Comment: Please include your jsfiddle code in the question. Also note that it's not a link at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you need to do is check the input and in case the total value exceeds 250, set the input that's been updated to a safe value, like so:

```
function updateSlider(obj){

    var id = obj.id;
    var sum = sum123();
    var oldValue = parseInt(obj.value);

    if(sum>250){
        //alert('Max reached');
        obj.value = 250 - sum + oldValue;
    }
    document.getElementById('span'+id).innerHTML = obj.value 
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2yLuj/5/)

Comment: Great. That was a perfect solution and simple too. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Hi Arjan, When I uncommented the alert the popups are repeating continuously. Can you suggest a workaround for that.

Comment: Found solution to the above comment. I removed the alert and placed div which worked.

Comment: updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kapilgopinath/2yLuj/9/

Comment: When you're using the mouse to drag something (like a slider) and you then get an alert box, the browser could keep the mouse in drag-mode after you've clicked 'OK' to close the alert box. It then still links mouse movement to slider movement, which can make it very easy for the alert to re-appear. The (easiest) solution is to not use alerts, as you already discovered.